# Can Visual Studio auto-create an inline, local anonymous method for an event instead of creating concrete method?

Tags: c#, .net, events, visual-studio-2017

When you use the `+=` operator to create an event handler, Visual Studio gives you the option to press TAB to auto-create the handler. Doing so creates a concrete method like so:

```
consoleListBox.OnKeyPress += ConsoleListBox_OnKeyPress;

private static void ConsoleListBox_OnKeyPress(ConsoleControl sender, ConsoleKeyInfo keyInfo)
{

}
```

But is it possible to have VS create a local, inline anomyous handler like this?

```
consoleListBox.OnKeyPress += (sender, keyInfo) =>
{

};
```

It's so much cleaner, especially if I don't need the handler outside of the current context. I create these manually for now, but it would be nice if there were a way to auto-create local handlers.

Comment: doesn't ctrl+space give you options of what to create?

Comment: @MartinUllrich Nope, it just displays an intellisense box showing all symbols available to the current context.

Comment: ReSharper can do this.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure Visual studio doesn't have an auto-complete for that. However, you can add your own code snippets which allow for some pretty cool things. I'd suggest you go look at Microsofts tutorial on how to do that [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/walkthrough-creating-a-code-snippet?view=vs-2019) .

You can add snippets for litterally every piece of code you would like. The page gives an example of an auto square root piece of code which you can then add by typing "sqrt" and pressing TAB. You can add variables in the code as well which then allows you to enter your own value ones you use the snippet.

In your case you could make a snippet called "inlineevent" or just "inevent" or something like that.

Good luck and have fun!

Comment: Snippets are just static templates with parameterized placeholders. I doubt snippets will work here as you would have to be able to infer the signature of the handler you're assigning to. That would be something a VS extension would be able to do barring any native VS feature.

Comment: Correct, however you could just add two parameters by default, since most events seem to use that many, And then just add one when its needed. Then you wouldn't have to create an entire VS Extension.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is not possible as Intellisense has standards for completion. However, if you want to replace these concrete methods with local inline anonymous methods for a large number of methods, you can let Visual Studio create the ordinary methods, then write a separate program to read the code file, track these methods and modify them as you desire.